# Bundler + Guard + Rspec + Rbenv = "You have already activated..."

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, guard, rbenv

`Guard` is always annoying me with this issue:

```
.../gems/bundler-1.6.2/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:34:in `block in setup': You have already activated multi_json 1.10.0, but your Gemfile requires multi_json 1.9.2. Prepending `bundle exec` to your command may solve this. (Gem::LoadError)
```

I know I can do `bundle update` or `gem uninstall` or specify the exact version in `Gemfile`.

Is there a way to fix it once and for all so guard launches `bundle exec rspec` or `bin/rspec` (I am using `rbenv`)? I think I saw a patch somewhere on github but I can't find it now.

**Update**

Just for the record here is what happening even with `bundle exec`:

```
$ bundle exec guard
17:11:07 - INFO - Guard is using TerminalNotifier to send notifications.
17:11:07 - INFO - Guard is using TerminalTitle to send notifications.
17:11:07 - INFO - Guard::RSpec is running
17:11:07 - INFO - Guard is now watching at '/Sites/site'
[1] guard(main)>
17:11:10 - INFO - Run all
17:11:10 - INFO - Running all specs
WARN: Unresolved specs during Gem::Specification.reset:
      rspec-expectations (~> 2.14.0)
      rspec-mocks (~> 2.14.0)
      listen (~> 2.7)
      formatador (>= 0.2.4)
WARN: Clearing out unresolved specs.
Please report a bug if this causes problems.
WARN: Unresolved specs during Gem::Specification.reset:
      debugger-ruby_core_source (~> 1.3.2)
      rb-inotify (>= 0.9)
WARN: Clearing out unresolved specs.
Please report a bug if this causes problems.
.../.rbenv/versions/2.1.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/bundler-1.6.2/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:34:in `block in setup': You have already activated formatador 0.2.5, but your Gemfile requires formatador 0.2.4. Prepending `bundle exec` to your command may solve this. (Gem::LoadError)
...
```

Comment: I'm not sure what the problem is. Can't you just do `bundle exec guard start`?

Comment: It doesn't do anything. The issue pops up once guard runs rspec.

Comment: https://github.com/guard/guard/issues/464

Answer (score 6, accepted):

So after lurking on it for a while I have amended `Guardfile` a bit:

Before:

```
guard :rspec do
```

After:

```
guard :rspec, cmd: 'bundle exec rspec' do
```

And that solved it once and for all.